# sharepoint 2016 calendar view all events

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint 2016 calendar(using month view) that holds a lot of events and I would like to have the calendar display all events and not just the first 3 of every day.

So I what to see all events unfolded when I load the calendar instead of having to click the "x more elements" link.

Can this be done using some scripts or is there a configuration that decides hvor many items there are displayed

/Birger

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately a calendar is just list with a fancy hard coded view, so you have quite a few options really, custom pages, custom webparts, script editors, etc.

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be use the "expand all" command, which can be called from JavaScript.

```
calendar.expandAll()
```

You could do this by embedding the JavaScript in the page in questions or just using a Script Editor Webpart on the page in question.

```
function(){  
     var calendar = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarInstanceRepository.firstInstance();
     if (calendar &amp;&amp; typeof calendar.expandAll === 'function') {calendar.expandAll();}
}
```

The only thing you need to be aware of is you need to execute this code after the calendar has loaded, you can do this in JavaScript but I don't have the code to hand.

This example uses waits to and check to see if the calendar has loaded.
https://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2016/08/16/expand-all-items-in-sharepoint-2013-calendar-to-show-more-than-three/